# Let $T$ be such that for every vertices $u,v$ there exists a unique walk joining them, then $T$ has no cycles and $T+e$ has exactly 1 cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a part of the proof of the following

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $T$ be such that for every vertices $u,v$ there exists a unique walk joining them, then $T$ has no cycles and $T+e$ has exactly 1 cycle.
>
> **Proof.** If $T$ had a cycle, say $<v_1,e_1,v_2,e_2,...,v_1>$ then there would exist two $v_1-v_2$ walks: $<v_1,e_1,v_2>$ and $v_2,e_2,...,v_1>$, thus $T$ has no cycles.
>
> Let $u,v \in V_T$. Let $e=\{u,v\}$ From hypothesis we have that there exists a walk $u-v$, concatenating this with the walk $<v,e,u>$ we have a cycle.
>
> Now, suppose $T+e$ had at least 2 cycles. Then $e$ would belong to two cycles in $T+e$. Then, in $T$ there would be two walks $u-v$, which is a contradiction$_\square$.

I understand everything up to the part where we have to prove that having 2 or more cycles in $T+e$ is impossible, I don't understand why would $e$ belonging to two cycles in $T+e$ implies that there are two differen walks from $u$ to $v$.

What am I missing?

Comment: $T$ has no cycles, so any cycle in $T+e$ must include the edge $e$; and any cycle containing $e$, minus $e$ itself, is a walk from $u$ to $v$.

Comment: I'm having trouble writing a more formal proof of that part of the theorem, could you elaborate a bit? All I can get are handwaving/showing a drawing arguments.

Answer (score 1):

(Greg Martin’s comment pretty much answers the question, but since the OP had trouble seven years ago filling in the details, it seems worthwhile to do so to get this off the unanswered list.)

Suppose that $T+e$ has cycles $C$ and $C'$. $T$ has no cycles, so both $C$ and $C'$ must contain the edge $e$. Thus, we can write

$$C=\langle u,e_1,w_1,\ldots,e_m,v,e\rangle$$

and

$$C'=\langle u,e_1',w_1',\ldots,e_n',v,e\rangle$$

for some $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $w_0,\ldots,w_m,w_0',\ldots,w_n'\in V_T$, and $e_1,\ldots,e_m,e_1',\ldots,e_n'\in E_T$. Clearly deleting $e$ from $C$ and $C'$ leaves walks

$$W=\langle u,e_1,w_1,\ldots,e_m,v\rangle$$

and

$$W'=\langle u,e_1',w_1',\ldots,e_n',v\rangle$$

from $u$ to $v$ in $T$. By hypothesis there is a unique walk in $T$ from $u$ to $v$, so $W=W'$, and therefore $C=W+e=W'+e=C'$. Thus, $T$ has only one cycle.